# Bootstrap Navbar hiccuping upon dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, onclick, navbar

I have a website I built using Bootstrap where I'm trying to (1) make my navbar drop down smoothly upon the "menu" button being clicked and (2) show overflow of the resulting "menu" options by being scrollable at about 90% display height(there will end up being around 25 items in the dropdown directory). Currently I've made overflow show but it's not scrollable so it's cut off.

When I inspect .navbar-collapse.collapse.in, the area it highlights orange is the area that shows before the hiccup happens and the rest of the men reveals itself. I've tried adjusting height of this element but can't get any changes to stick.

I don't have the element .navbar-collapse.collapsing in my CSS but I see it flicker when the directory is triggered ("menu" tab is clicked).

For issue #2, when the dropdown menu gets to (I believe) 768px height, it pauses on its descent to the bottom of the webpage for a milisecond then continues to reveal.

Full code below minus irrelevant body lines and website [here](https://1hungryhunny.com/eckhauslatta.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>BURNOUT</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link file="font" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<style>

body{
    background-color: #fff5de;
}

.row-bio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33vh;
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-left: 50%;
    padding-right: 50%;
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.img-bio {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    padding-left: 28px;
   
}
    
    
h7 {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Gothambook", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
    
h6 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    letter-spacing: 1.4vw;
    transform: scale(1,1.6);
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px!important;
    }

    
img {
     height: 33vh;
    }
    
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
    
.container{   
    width: 100vw;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 32px;
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 50vh;
}
    
.scrolling-wrapper, .scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
                          display: none;
                         }
 }
    
    
@font-face {
    font-family: Gothambook;
    src: url(/Gotham-Book.otf);
}
    
    
.modal-dialog {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
.close {
        text-shadow: 0 0px 0;
        font-size: 44px;
        line-height: .6;
        color: black;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
.close:hover {
        color: red;
    }
    
.modal-backdrop{
        opacity:0!important;
    }
    
.modal-content {
        border-radius: 26px;
    }

.modal-header {
        border-bottom: .5px solid #fa4010;
        background-color: #fa4010;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
.modal-title {
            font-family:"Fairfax",  Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: white;
        padding: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: .1em;
    }
    
.modal-body {
         font-family: Gothambook;
         line-height: 1.5;
         font-weight: 400;
         color: black;
         font-size: 20px;
         padding-right: 40px;
         padding-left: 40px;
         padding-bottom: 36px;
         padding-top: 36px;
         box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
         background-color: #FFF5DE;
         border-radius: 20px;
         border: 5px solid black;
    }
    

.btn {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 21px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    
.btn-primary
    {
       display: flex;
       float: right;
     margin-right: 6%;
       color: black;
       font-family: Arial;
       letter-spacing: .2vw;
    background-color: #FFF5DE;
    justify-content: center;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 10%;
    }
    
.btn-secondary
    {
        display: flex;
     margin-left: 6%;
       color: black;
              font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #FFF5DE;
           letter-spacing: .2vw;
    justify-content: center;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 10%;
    }
    
.btn-secondary:hover
    {background-color: #ff5512;}
    
.btn-secondary:active
    {background-color: #f1e119;}
    
.btn-secondary:focus
    {background-color: #f1e119;}

    
.btn-primary:hover
    {
       color: black;
       background-color: #ed440f;
       border-color: black;
    }
    
.btn-primary:focus
    {
       color: black;
       background-color: #19ffd6;
       border-color: black;
    }
.btn-primary:active
    {background-color: #f1e119;}
    
    
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    width: 91%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 0%;    
    }
    
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
     display: block !important; 
     margin-top: 46px!important; 
     border-top: 0px solid black;
    }
    
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
    width: 91%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    }
                
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    width: 91%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 0%;    
    }
        
    
.container-fluid {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        background: #FFF5DE;
        height: 52px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
.nav>li>a {
        z-index: 30000;
         box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
    }
    
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a
    {background-color: #FFF5DE;
    }
    
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover 
    {background-color: #fa4010;}
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a 
    {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: .04em;
    }
    
.navbar-toggle 
    {z-index: 11000;}
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar
    {background-color: black;}
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover
    {background-color: #ff5512;}
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:active
    {background-color: #f1e119;}
    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus
    {background-color: #f1e119;}
    
        
.navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }
.navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }
.navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none!important;
        }
.navbar-nav {
            float: none!important;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
.nav {
            padding-left: 3%;
            float: none!important;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
.navbar-nav>li {
            float: none;
        }
.navbar-nav>li>a {
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-bottom: 6px;
        }
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
             display: block !important; 
             margin-top: 46px!important; 
             border-top: 0px solid black;
             
             overflow: visible;}
         
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
        margin-top: 46px;
                 border-top: 0px solid black;
        
    }
    
      

    
    
    
    

@media all and (max-width: 500px)  {
    
h6 {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    letter-spacing: .1vw;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 100;
    transform: scale(1,3);
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    }
    
.btn-secondary
    {
    width: 18%;!important;
    letter-spacing: -.1vw;
    margin-left: 4%;
    }
    
.btn-primary
    {
    width: 18%;!important;
    letter-spacing: -.1vw;
    margin-right: 4%;
    }
}


@media all and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px)  {
    
h6 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    letter-spacing: -.1vw;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 100;
    transform: scale(1,1.8);
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary
    {
    width: 17%;!important;
    }
    
.btn-primary
    {
    width: 17%;!important;
    }
    
}


 @media (min-width: 1000px)
 {
.modal-dialog {width: 80vw;}
}

@media (max-width: 1200px)  {
    
    .modal-content {
        width: 80vw%;
        margin-left: 10vw;
        margin-right: 10vw;
        margin-top: 100px;
        border-radius: 26px;
    }
}



    </style>
    
  
    
    <script>
    
        function closeWindow() {
            document.getElementById("myNavbar").classList.toggle("in");
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="mNavbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
                     Bio
                 </button>
             
               
                
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#myNavbar" >
               Menu
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
              <h6> ECKHAUS-LATTA </h6>
    
        <div onclick="closeWindow()"  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="#eckhauslatta.html" class="uruna">Eckhaus Latta</a> </li>
            <li><a href="/helmutlang.html" class="uruna">Helmut Lang</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interviews" class="uruna">Carol Christian Poell</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pergotesson.html" class="uruna">Per Gotesson</a></li>
            <li><a href="/elenavelez.html" class="uruna">Elena Velez</a></li>
             <li><a href="#eckhauslatta.html" class="uruna">Eckhaus Latta</a> </li>
            <li><a href="/helmutlang.html" class="uruna">Helmut Lang</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interviews" class="uruna">Carol Christian Poell</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pergotesson.html" class="uruna">Per Gotesson</a></li>
            <li><a href="/elenavelez.html" class="uruna">Elena Velez</a></li>
             <li><a href="#eckhauslatta.html" class="uruna">Eckhaus Latta</a> </li>
            <li><a href="/helmutlang.html" class="uruna">Helmut Lang</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interviews" class="uruna">Carol Christian Poell</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pergotesson.html" class="uruna">Per Gotesson</a></li>
            <li><a href="/elenavelez.html" class="uruna">Elena Velez</a></li>
             <li><a href="#eckhauslatta.html" class="uruna">Eckhaus Latta</a> </li>
            <li><a href="/helmutlang.html" class="uruna">Helmut Lang</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interviews" class="uruna">Carol Christian Poell</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pergotesson.html" class="uruna">Per Gotesson</a></li>
            <li><a href="/elenavelez.html" class="uruna">Elena Velez</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          </ul>
     
      </div>
           </div>
    </nav>a
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       </button>
                     <div class="img-bio">
                          <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS17_8.jpg">
                         </div>
        
      This paper investigates the ways in which members of the digital gig economy, specifically content moderators and Amazon Mechanical Turk workers, experience occupational distress through burnout and vicarious traumatization. In order to understand this, I conducted interviews with 6 individuals who have had significant experience working either as platform workers or content moderators: 4 work primarily on Amazon Mechanical Turk and 2 worked formerly as content moderators full-time, although one active Turk worker (Turker) has done significant amounts of content moderation work on the platform. This work builds upon research done by Sarah Roberts, whose significant contributions to content moderation research guided my approach to interviewing moderators; Manuel Castells, Guy Standing, and David Bell, whose work I use in order to situate content moderation and Amazon Mechanical Turk within the information society, network society and gig economy; and Laurie Anne Pearlman, Grant Devilly, Renee Wright and Tracy Varker, whose research frameworks I use to analyze the ways that my interview subjects fit into, and defy, definitions put forth of vicarious trauma and burnout. My findings are that Amazon Mechanical Turk workers experience burnout and anxiety due to feelings of uncertainty about future financial security. This is caused primarily by the design of the platform and the nature of the piecework which happens on it: workers’ lack of guaranteed compensation, the possibility of being unfairly punished and having their future prospects negatively affected; and the uncertainty of whether enough jobs will be available to pay necessary bills. The Turkers who I interviewed reported that crowd-sourced support systems allowed them to improve these feelings of uncertainty, or precarity. My findings about workers on both platforms who were exposed to graphic content is that little training was given to prepare them for witnessing trauma-inducing content, yet the distress that exposure to this content caused was more a result of pressure to meet production requirements and as a result of burnout in general. This has implications for the ways in which occupational distress affects platform workers in the digital economy.
              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
     
 <div class="container">
              <div class="row scrolling-wrapper">
                  <h7>FW12</h7>
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_1.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_3.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_5.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_6.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_7.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_8.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_9.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_10.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_11.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_12.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_13.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_14.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_15.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_16.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_17.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW12_18.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="row scrolling-wrapper">
                        <h7>SS12</h7>
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_1.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_2.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_3.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_4.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_6.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_7.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_8.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_9.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_10.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_11.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_12.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_13.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_14.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_15.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_16.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_17.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_18.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_19.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_20.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_21.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_22.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_23.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_24.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_SS13_25.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row scrolling-wrapper">
                        <h7>FW13</h7>
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_1.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_3.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_4.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_5.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_6.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_7.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_8.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_9.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_10.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_11.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_12.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_13.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_14.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_15.jpg">
                            <img src="/ASSETS/EL_FW13_16.jpg">
                    </div>
                          </div>
                
            
            
            
            </body>
            </html>
```